# Why is "Goog" stock considered uncertain now?

Tags: stocks

Having a look at: [macrotrends](https://www.macrotrends.net/stocks/charts/GOOG/alphabet/stock-price-history)

I do not really know much about finance. Though it puzzled me that in the waves of layoffs at FB, Twitter and other big techs, many article over the webs seem to worry about google by association.

Basically, the company capitalised over the covid period. Most of its extra gross earnings have been preserved, but it was over-optimistic in its spending. Making the net revenue go down once covid was over and macro-economics wind were opposite. Even though, these net revenues are still very much positive and nearly twice as much as pre-covid...

- Revenue and gross profit are still increasing by significant amount.
- Net income over 12 months at end of September is twice more than year 2019
- Earning per share is still 1.06/88.65 ~ 1.2% of its value
- Google share in Active Monthly User for search is still ahead of competition by a solid margin
- Hardware departments revenue are consistently getting better (ex: Pixel)

Are these articles over pessimistic? Or can somebody understanding more than me explain to me why would google consider layoffs? Or be considered by any mean to have a "hard time"?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Are these articles over pessimistic?

No one knows. For every article or analyst that downgrades a share, there is another one who recommends buying it. [For example.](https://www.fool.com/investing/2022/11/08/alphabet-stock-is-a-buy-and-its-all-thanks-to-goog/)

At some point I owned a fair chunk of stock from a previous employer and so for a while I tracked the forecasts and comments.  They were all over the place and none were anywhere close to what actually happened.

In reality all these predictions and analyses are useless. The stock market is inherently unpredictable, regardless of how much you analyze trends and numbers. You would think that mutual funds that are run by highly paid expert fund managers would perform better than a simple index fund like the S&P 500. They don't. The vast majority actually performs worse.

If there happens to a be person that actually knows how to predict this with higher accuracy than just random chance, they most likely just enjoy their own wealth and have no incentive to share their insights.